# facing CORS error while downloading image through html2canvas in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, html2canvas, namecheap

I am facing CORS error while downloading the image from a given url from a laravel api.
when i download the image it is blanked . but through the laravel api i am able to show the image  in React.js app

the error which i received in a console

```
Access to image at 'https://api.osdtrips.com/images/781595409240.png' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 


cache-storage.ts:131 GET https://api.osdtrips.com/images/781595409240.png net::ERR_FAILED


index.js:1 17375d3eb78 503ms Error loading image https://api.osdtrips.com/images/781595409240.png
```

I am using React.js as a front end & Laravel as a back-end .

and here is the code that i am using in react.js for downloading the image :-

```
downloadImage() {
 html2canvas(document.querySelector("#divToPrint"), {
  logging: true,
  letterRendering: 1,
  allowTaint: true,
  useCORS: true,
  scrollX: 0,
  scrollY: -window.scrollY,

  async: true,
}).then((canvas) => {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = canvas
    .toDataURL("image/png")
    .replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
  a.download = "somefilename.jpg";
  a.click();
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There is no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header associated with the resource.

It means that the Same Origin Policy is enforced as normal. No origins are granted permission. Only the resource's origin.

Could you download all the needed assets and use them locally?

Comment: I am fetching the image url api and show the image in react app and then i download the single image when user click on it after doing some editing

Comment: so , the user need to do some editing and after the editing he can download the image so that's why i am using html2canvas for taking the div screenshot but when i download the image after editing it is blanked when i add the image through local assets of react.js then it shows after the download and working fine it has only problem with when i download the image from url .

Comment: Maybe this could help
https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2canvas
See
"It doesn't magically circumvent any browser content policy restrictions either, so rendering cross-origin content will require a proxy to get the content to the same origin."